Spark context jarOfClass method is returning None.get error
I am using Spark 3.3.3 with Java 1.8 in a springboot 1.4.7 application.
When I executed
sparkSession.sparkContext().addJar(sparkSession.sparkContext().jarOfClass(MyClass.class));
it gives following None.get error.
17:01:46.771 [http-nio-9402-exec-10] ERROR o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[.[dispatcherServlet] - Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is java.util.NoSuchElementException: None.get] with root cause
java.util.NoSuchElementException: None.get
        at scala.None$.get(Option.scala:529)
        at scala.None$.get(Option.scala:527)


The code compiles fine, but an exception occurs when that particular line is executed.
Moreover, it works when I run it with spark-master local[*].
But if I try to connect to a spark cluster, the error occurs.
I tried to put jarFileLocation directly into addJar() function and it worked.
sparkSession.sparkContext().addJar(jarFileLocation)
So there is an issue with sparkSession.sparkContext().jarOfClass(MyClass.class)
I tried other answers in other questions related to this, but they didn't work.
it is not a versioning issue.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

it is already clear enough for humans i think. none the less, i found the answer. but this question wasnt asked on stackoverflow before this so i am keeping the question and answer.

I found a solution for this. The issue was how the application was being run.
I was running the application using maven. And sparkContext.jarOfClass() was fetching file resource and trying to find the "jar" file from which this class was called.
if (uriStr.startsWith("jar:file:")) {

Refer to this code SparkContext jarOfClass
But because maven run uses folder structuring and does not run the application using built jar file, it was unable to find the "jar" file.
when I tried to run using java -jar myProgram.jar it started working.
PS: keeping this here if someone faces same issue in the future, thanks
